# CodeIgniter produces array of arrays

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm trying to a straightforward resultset as an array, from CodeIgniter, and I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong. Maybe something has changed with CodeIgniter 3.0.4 which I am now using.

I'm trying to get a simple array that I can pass directly to a view dropdown box. Instead I am getting a multi dimensional array which I have to decode.

I've tried various methods without success:

- result()
- result_array()
- row_array()

What on earth am I missing?

```
$strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT PurchasingGroup FROM snapshot";
$query=$this->db->query($strSQL);
$data=$query->result_array();

Array ( [0] => Array ( [PurchasingGroup] => AAA ) [1] => Array ( [PurchasingGroup] => BBB ) [2] => Array ( [PurchasingGroup] => CCC ) [3] => Array ( [PurchasingGroup] => DDD) [4] => Array ( [PurchasingGroup] => EEE ) [5] => Array ( [PurchasingGroup] => P&P Deve ) [6] => Array ( [PurchasingGroup] => FFF ) [7] => Array ( [PurchasingGroup] => GGG ) [8] => Array ( [PurchasingGroup] => HHH ) [9] => Array ( [PurchasingGroup] => III ) [10] => Array ( [PurchasingGroup] => JJJ ) [11] => Array ( [PurchasingGroup] => KKK) [12] => Array ( [PurchasingGroup] => LLL ) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you expect, but your result is perfectly normal: it is an array of the rows from your query, and in each row you have the fields (in our case, only one field).

The result is also coherent with [Codeigniter documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html).

To obtain single rows, you have to perform a loop, like:

```
foreach( $data as $row )
{
    // $row['PurchasingGroup'] is your field value
}
```

If you want a flat-array of `PurchasingGroup` values, you can use (on PHP >= 5.5) the `array_column` function:

```
$flatArray = array_column( $data, 'PurchasingGroup' );
```

**Edit:**

On PHP < 5.5, you can simulate `array_column` in this way:

```
$flatArray = array_map
(
    function( $row ) { return $row['PurchasingGroup']; }, 
    $data
);
```

---

- See more about [CodeIgniter Query Results](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)
- See more about [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

Comment: Excellent! Thanks so much, just what I was looking for.      $flatArray = array_column( $data, 'PurchasingGroup' );

Comment: What is the best method? seems like the array_column is a hacky way to achieve this. Or maybe it's specifically made for that purpose

Answer (score 3):

make this resultset from multi dimensional array to simple array? if question this ,you can reference follow:

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
    echo $row['title'];
    echo $row['name'];
    echo $row['body'];
    // You can re-assembled into an array
}
```